# magento-how to disable billing address in checkout for virtual products?

Tags: magento

I have read so many articles saying that the virtual products won't have billing address in checkout. But I am getting billing address for virtual product.Can anyone help me out by saying how to disable it for virtual products??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you got it wrong. When performing a checkout and the cart has only virtual products then you don't have a **shipping address**. Billing address is always there. You need to bill your customers.

Comment: @Marius I have a situation where customer will collect the product from one of our store,therefore we need to bybass billing step. now in this case?